# Why the plane can not taxi backward?

Tags: aircraft-design

This is a news from [Indonesian  local news](https://travel.detik.com/travel-news/d-3856785/heboh-pesawat-garuda-didorong-orang-orang-ini-penjelasannya?_ga=2.194396397.1368287623.1518070168-1765362511.1413772346)

This is the translations from google translate.

> Tambolaka - Garuda Indonesia plane seems broken and pushed by people.
>   This is a complete explanation from Garuda Indonesia.
>
> The incident was crowded on social media and commented on by various
>   netizens. Considering this, Senior Manager of Public Relations of
>   Garuda Indonesia Ikhsan Rosan raised his voice and explained it.
>
> "It just happened today, it's at Tambolaka Airport (Southwest Sumba,
>   East Nusa Tenggara-red)," he told detikTravel, Friday (8/2/2018).
>
> Ikhsan Rosan asserted, the CRJ type aircraft is not broken. Instead,
>   the plane was a little too far as it landed and passed through the
>   apron, the aircraft parking lot.
>
> "The plane should be landing go straight to the left to the apron."
>   Well, he passed a little, "he added.
>
> Then why should be pushed by people?
>
> "Because there's no pushback car, that's what drives the plane, so it
>   seems that it is driven by technicians and airport officers," Ikhsan
>   Rosan replied.
>
> Ikhsan Rosan confirmed, Garuda aircraft flight is fine. Everything is
>   running smoothly

[image]

My Question is : Is it True that the plane can not taxi backward, so if it pass it's apron, people or a push back car must  push the plane back? Why The plane manufacturer do not give the ability to the plane to move backward?

Comment: You got it right... planes have engine (s) pushing only in one direction (forward) and wheels are not powered. This is to save costs, and usually is not a problem.

Comment: This is unlikely a very standard procedure, to have so many people pushing the airliner by hands. Probably better title it would be "What is going on here, and why?"

Comment: The linked question explains that it *should* be possible. However if they already shut down, it might have been simpler to get people to push it than to start the engines up again and get somebody to indicate to the pilots where to go as they don't have rear visibility and then still burn quite a bit of fuel in the process.